# How do I plot a pie chart using Pandas with this data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like this

```
ID   Sex   Smoke
1  female    1 
2    male    0
3   female   1
```

How do I plot a pie chart to show how many male or female smokes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Say you start with:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import pie, axis, show

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sex': ['female', 'male', 'female'],
    'Smoke': [1, 1, 1]})
```

You can always do something like this:

```
sums = df.Smoke.groupby(df.Sex).sum()
axis('equal');
pie(sums, labels=sums.index);
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can plot directly with pandas selecting `pie` chart:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex': ['female', 'male', 'female'], 'Smoke': [1, 3, 1]})

df.Smoke.groupby(df.Sex).sum().plot(kind='pie')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

here is a one liner :

```
temp[temp.Smoke==1]['Sex'].value_counts().plot.pie()
```